# How to run Console Application in Background (no UI)?

Tags: .net, console-application, background-process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.Net Console Application that Doesn’t Bring up a Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934901/net-console-application-that-doesnt-bring-up-a-console)

I have a console application written in VB.NET that will become a scheduled task on a web server.  It will run every ten minutes.  The problem is that every ten minutes it displays the empty black CMD window while processing, which can be distracting.  How can I configure it to run in the background (with no CMD window displayed)?

Comment: You might want to consider a windows service that wakes up every 10 minutes.

Comment: Please vote to close.  I found a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934901/net-console-application-that-doesnt-bring-up-a-console

Comment: Although this may be a duplicate of the question listed, the answer here helped me more than any of the answers listed in the duplicate question as it told me the exact steps I needed to take

Comment: @Rachel the the answer should be migrated to the other question - flag it for a moderator to do

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Set on your Project in "Application" the Output Type to "Windows Application".

Comment: I definitely like this solution better than the accepted in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934901/net-console-application-that-doesnt-bring-up-a-console