# Use threads with windows form c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I would like to use thread in a few functions in my windows form.

I have a button that would add and check if the input was correct over 4k items **in order** to the listview in my form, but the form freezes until its over executing the function and then all the items show up at once.
I would like to know how can I see the items being added one by one using threads without the form freezing.I read about threads and background worker(https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms171728(v=VS.110).aspx) but I didnt understand it very well how to link a function with the background worker,or how to call the thread safely(got confused with delegate part).
And how can I make it call a function after the thread is done?

```
This is what I'm trying but its giving "InvalidOperationException" at 2 places: 

 - when I try to add the item to my listView at
   "lissView1.Items.Add(tempItem)" in the of "bw1_DoWork" loop.


 - When I try "String temp = ..." inside the "Parallel.For":






    namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
    {




public partial class mainForm : Form
    {
    private BackgroundWorker bw1;

    public mainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            formLoad();
            bw1 = new BackgroundWorker();
            bw1.DoWork += bw1_DoWork;
        }

    private void pasteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         bw1.RunWorkerAsync(Clipboard.GetText());
    }   


    private void bw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e){
        String temp = "";
            int n;
            ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem tempSubItem;
            ListViewItem tempItem;
        String cp =(String) e.Argument;
            string[] stringSeparators = new string[] { "\r\n" };
            string[] rows = cp.Split(stringSeparators, StringSplitOptions.None);
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.Length-1; i++)
            {
                tempItem = new ListViewItem(rows[i].Split('\t'));
                tempItem.UseItemStyleForSubItems = false;

                tempSubItem = new ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem();
                tempSubItem.BackColor = Color.Green;
                tempSubItem.Text = "NORMAL";
                temp = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", TextBox0.Text, tempItem.SubItems[1].Text);
                if (!File.Exists(temp))
                {
                    tempItem.SubItems[1].BackColor = Color.Red;
                    tempSubItem.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    tempSubItem.Text = "ERRO";
                }
                temp = String.Format("{0}\\{1}", TextBox1.Text, tempItem.SubItems[2].Text);
                if (!File.Exists(temp))
                {
                    tempItem.SubItems[2].BackColor = Color.Red;
                    tempSubItem.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    tempSubItem.Text = "ERRO";
                }
                if (int.TryParse(tempItem.SubItems[0].Text, out n))
                {
                    if (n > networkList.Items.Count)
                    {
                        tempItem.SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
                        tempSubItem.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        tempSubItem.Text = "ERRO";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    tempItem.SubItems[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
                    tempSubItem.BackColor = Color.Red;
                    tempSubItem.Text = "ERRO";
                }
                try
                {
                    tempItem.SubItems[4] = tempSubItem;
                }
                catch (ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
                {
                    tempItem.SubItems.Add(tempSubItem);
                }

                lissView1.Items.Add(tempItem);
            }
        }

    private void interactiveRunButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
         ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions();
            options.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4;
            Parallel.For(0, inputList.Items.Count,
                   index =>
                   {
                       testex(String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3}", listView1.Items[index].SubItems[0].Text, listView1.Items[index].SubItems[1].Text, listView1.Items[index].SubItems[2].Text, listView1.Items[index].SubItems[3].Text));
                   });
    }
    static void testex(string f)
    {
        Process compiler = new Process();
            compiler.StartInfo.FileName = "testex.exe";
            compiler.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
            compiler.StartInfo.Arguments =f;
            compiler.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            compiler.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            compiler.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(compiler.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can look at the following  `System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden`

Answer (score 1):

You need to user BackgroundWorker if you want  that your UI will be responsive. Here you have a documentation about it http://www.albahari.com/threading/part3.aspx#_BackgroundWorker

**Another problem is a function that I would like to execute faster by calling more than 1 thread, this one doesnt need to be in order. Its also from a button:**

Then again you can use Parallel library. Parallel.Foreach method will be usefull to achive your goal. Here you have the same link http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_Parallel.For_and_Parallel.ForEach

Comment: Its giving invalidOperarionException

Comment: @kadzu if you say `BackgroundWorker` is buggy, it don't think so. If you say *my code doesn't work*, then you should post the code you used with BackgroundWorker and where you get this exception. We are not magicians....

Comment: Did you read the link that I copied? There is an example in case you are confuse. You need to understand delegate first to use it of course. BackgroundWorker use a delegate that invokes a method with the following signature YourMethod (object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)   , I think that this is the link that you need, so you can subscribe to that event backgroundworker.DoWork += YourMethod and then you can start backgroundworker.RunWorkerAsync(yourparam)

Answer (score 0):

For hiding the console window, look in to this possible duplicate:

[.Net Console Application that Doesn't Bring up a Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934901/net-console-application-that-doesnt-bring-up-a-console)

For threading you will need to control the number of threads in order to avoid flooding your machine. Consider using the [Thread Pool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ka9477y(v=vs.110).aspx)

If you are using .Net 4.0+, PLinQ will do the job elegantly with a parallel for loop. [Options here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853907/limit-the-number-of-parallel-threads-in-c-sharp).